# Python *args AttributeError

Tags: python, attributeerror, args

can anyone help me to figure out why the first code works and second dont?:

Working code

```
alias = []
alias.append(cx_Oracle.connect('%s/%s@%s' % (username, password, base)))
solve(*alias, **binds)

def solve(*alias, **binds):
    cur = alias[0].cursor()
```

Not working code

```
alias = []
alias.append(cx_Oracle.connect('%s/%s@%s' % (username, password, base)))
solve(alias, binds)

def solve(*alias, **binds):
    cur = alias[0].cursor()
```

Error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cursor'

*** Thanks all! That was very helpfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in [Keyword Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) `**binds`, [Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) `*alias` and [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) `solve(alias, binds)` vs `solve(*alias, **binds)`.

When you call `solve(alias, binds)`, both arguments `alias` and `binds` are assigned to the formal parameter `*alias`.

This results in `alias[0]` being the list `[ cx_Oracle.connect('%s/%s@%s' % (username, password, base)) ]` instead of just the first element `cx_Oracle.connect('%s/%s@%s' % (username, password, base))`. And the list `[...]` doesn't have an attribute 'cursor', as Python aptly complains.

Answer (score 3):

The issue occurs because in the second case, since you are not unpacking the list or dictionary when passing as argument to the function, they are passed into the `alias` as such (that is inside the solve function `alias`'s first element is the list `alias` , and `alias`'s second element is the dictionary `binds` ).

Example to show this -

```
>>> def a(*nargs, **kwargs):
...     print('nargs : ',nargs)
...     print('kwargs : ',kwargs)
...
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> d = {'a':2,'b':4}
>>> a(*x,**d)
nargs :  (1, 2, 3)
kwargs :  {'a': 2, 'b': 4}
>>> a(x,d)
nargs :  ([1, 2, 3], {'a': 2, 'b': 4})
kwargs :  {}
```

Answer (score 1):

`alias` is a `tuple` of all the arguments that were passed. If you pass it a `list`, `alias` will be a `tuple` that contains one element, a `list`. Instead, you want to unpack that `list` into separate elements. Then, `alias` will be a `tuple` that contains each of those elements.

```
>>> def a(*arg):
...     print(arg)
...
>>> a([1,2])
([1, 2],)
>>> a(*[1,2])
(1, 2)
```

The same goes for the `**binds` (if you were using it) - it's not expecting a dictionary, it's expecting the *elements from* a dictionary, so if you already had a ready-made dictionary, you would have to pass it in its unpacked form with `**`.

Answer (score 1):

`solve` takes any number of arguments and keyword arguments. the `*alias` argument is a list of the given normal arguments and `**binds` is a list of the given keyword arguments.

`*alias` *unpacks* `alias` to the arguments, for example:

```python
array = [1, 2, 3]
solve(*array) # same as solve(1, 2, 3)
```

Similarly, `**binds` unpacks `binds` as keyword arguments.

```python
map = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
solve(**map) # same as solve(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

This is the working code.

```python
solve(*alias, **binds)
```

If `alias` was `[1, 2, 3]` and `binds` was `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`, then this call is equivalent to

```python
solve(1, 2, 3, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

This results in the following:

```python
def solve(*alias, **binds):
    # alias is now the argument list
    # [1, 2, 3]
    # bind is now the keyword argument map
    # {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
    cur = alias[0].cursor()
```

This is the other one.

```python
solve(alias, binds)
```

Again, let's see what happens if `alias` was `[1, 2, 3]` and `binds` was `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`. Then this call is equivalent to

```python
solve([1, 2, 3], {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})

def solve(*alias, **binds):
    # alias is now the argument list 
    # [[1, 2, 3], {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}]
    # bind is now keyword argument map
    # {}
    cur = alias[0].cursor()
```

Comment: The commonly-used term is "unpacks" rather than "spreads," by the way.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks, got too used to ES6 terms lately.